# I can't install latest Wine (1.7.8)

Tags: wine, winetricks

Please help me to install WIne 1.7.8 on Ubuntu 12.04.
I added ppa, updated but it installing for me 1.7.11 instead 1.7.8...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install older versions, you have to download it from another source. What most people forget is from the WineHQ PPA, the older versions are removed from the repository.

Try this steps out:

```
sudo apt-get install flex bison qt3-dev-tools qt4-qmake
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/wine/wine-1.7.8.tar.bz2
tar-xjvf wine-1.7. *
cd wine-1.7. *

32bit architecture perform the following command:

    . / Configure
    cd tools;. / wineinstall 

>> 64bit architecture perform the following command:

    . / Configure - enable-win64
    cd tools;. / wineinstall
```

Answer (score 2):

To Install `Winehq 1.7.8` via PPA in Ubuntu 12.04

open Terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

Comment: Sorry, but with this command only possible to install 1.7.11. These command won't install 1.7.8!

Comment: Have you try it?

Comment: This is stated in the official website http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Comment: Yes I tried this command but they will get me only 1.7.11

Comment: I just found that 1.7.8 is gone from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa

Comment: Ok something wrong has been raised to do that